# load and dispose textures during runtime

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to understand how to be memory efficient in three.js. In my main application i try to load and dispose textures depending on the distance to the camera to save memory in the gpu. Since i work with a lot of textures and large textures in my main application i can't possibly work with a texture atlas into which i initially load all the textures. Here I have a code example of how i imagine it. Loading the texture works but not deleting it. But i don't see why that is. According to the three.js docu this should work with dispose() but it doesn't work here.Wwhere is my mistake?

In general: If someone thinks there is something in my concept that could be improved, i'd be happy to hear your advice. I only do what i do within the framework of what i can best imagine based on what i know so far. I like to learn about it. For example, i would be interested in how i not only load and dispose textures. Also the object that i have created here should be efficiently added and deleted as a whole, added again and deleted, ... after all, that's the purpose of class objects, being able to be created and deleted again at will.

```
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, container, aspect;

var cube;
    
async function main() {
await init();
animate();
}


async function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000 );  
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight; 
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, aspect, 1, 1000000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.enabled = true;
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    
    //------End three.js setup-------
    

    cube = new Cube();
    scene.add(cube.box);

}//-------End init----------


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );  
    render();
    
}//-------End animate----------

function render() {
    
    var distance = camera.position.distanceTo( cube.box.position );
    cube.update(distance);

    
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 

}//-------End render----------



class Cube{
    constructor(){
    
        this.texture;
        this.texstatus = false;
    
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 ); 
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            color: 0x00ff00,
            map: null
        } ); 
        this.box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); 
    
    
    }//end constructor
    
    update(distToCam){
    
        if(distToCam <= 100 && this.texstatus == false){
        
            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            this.texture = loader.load("grass.jpg");
            this.box.material.map = this.texture;       
            this.texstatus = true;  
        }
        
        if(distToCam > 100 && this.texstatus == true){
        
            //prvious solution deactivated 
            //this.texture.dispose();
            //this.texstatus = false;   

            //new solution
            this.box.material.map = null;
            this.texture.dispose();
            this.texstatus = false; 
            this.texture = undefined;

        }
        
        this.box.material.needsUpdate = true;
        
    }//end update
    

}//end Cube class
```

Comment: "Also the object that i have created here should be efficiently added and deleted as a whole, added again and deleted." Just remember that JavaScript is garbage collected. If you create and destroy an object over and over, you will see memory usage go up and up and up, then drop, then up and up and up, then drop.

Comment: ok then I now understand how the garbage collector works, it first collects before it suddenly releases larger storage space. but that doesn't explain why this.texture.dispose(); has no effect.

Comment: I implemented a new solution. This is how it works when zooming out. I can't say whether that's a clean solution, because I haven't yet understood why I don't see any effect with this.texture.dispose();

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the texture not be deleted? In memory usage? In the render? In a heap dump? Remember to also update your `Material`, otherwise three.js won't know to send the new data to the GPU. `this.box.material.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: I program on the tablet. I use text fields to display the values ​​of variables. when I call dispose I would have expected something to change in the text field and not [obect object] to remain.

Comment: Nothing in your question nor your code indicates this unique environment. The call to `Texture.dispose()` deallocates GPU memory, nothing more. The objects still remain. And even if you assign an object's value to a text field, that field won't change until you set a new value. If possible, I _highly_ recommend using a desktop so you can access developer tools that can show you the real values you're looking for, even if you just bridge your tablet to the desktop as a remote debugger.

Comment: ah ok learned something again, thank you very much. That helps me alot. I not only want to do things that I do, I also want to understand them